# Run script after div has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension and need to run some function after specific div has loaded on some page.
This div load via ajax and I can't bind a success function on this ajax.

I tried to do $('.div').load but it doesn't works.

So when I run my function in the Chrome console, it works perfectly.

Is it posible to do what I want?

My code:

```
$('.specialdiv').load(function() {
    console.log('loaded');
    $('._38 p').click(function () {
        var message_text = $(this).text();
        console.log(message_text);
    });
});
```

Comment: please update your question with the part of code you are not able to make work properly

Comment: .specialdiv is a class , if you are looking for a div with the id specialdiv use $('#specialdiv')

Comment: Why don't you precise a page to target the load ? Like $('div').load('page.php', function () { // callback });

Comment: give us your html aswell so we know what you are trying to accomplish exactly

Comment: What do you mean,  you can't access the success callback?  can you explain why?

Answer (score -2):

according to the jQuery API(http://api.jquery.com/load/), `load` is looking like this:

```
.load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )
```

i wonder where the obligatory `url` paramater is in your example.
your ajax-code should look like this in my opinion:

```
$('.specialdiv').load( "my_url.html", function() {
    console.log('loaded');  
});
```

and you can bind your click-event to elements that are loaded by ajax like this, anywhere in your code:

```
$(document)on('click', '._38 p', function () {
    var message_text = $(this).text();
    console.log(message_text);
});
```

Comment: (Yes, it's a mess and that's why it's deprecated, but it's there; using `.on("load", ...)` would be non-ambiguous)

Comment: So, now that you know, do you understand that your answer is _not relevant_?

Comment: @Xan so what? are you bored or something?